# PHP unable write to sys_get_temp_dir() on Mac

Tags: php, macos, permissions, osx-snow-leopard, user-permissions

I have really simplified it do to: `mkdir(sys_get_temp_dir().'/test', 0777);` which returns error

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in

Not sure what has happened (had quite a few problems recently with my Mac) although it appears as though it is a simple permissions problem somewhere.

```
sys_get_temp_dir() = /var/folders/aP/aPaKHnXDGqG-75bSdcDjkk+++TI/-Tmp-

sh-3.2# ls -ld /var/folders/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 12 Jul 00:51 /var/folders/
sh-3.2# ls -ld /var/folders/aP/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 12 Jul 00:40 /var/folders/aP/
sh-3.2# ls -ld /var/folders/aP/aPaKHnXDGqG-75bSdcDjkk+++TI/
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser  staff  136 12 Jul 00:44 /var/folders/aP/aPaKHnXDGqG-75bSdcDjkk+++TI/
```

- Using Snow Leopard 10.6.8
- MAMP Pro with Memcache extension.

Comment: Execute `whoami` in your terminal. Is user myuser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open up your terminal on your mac and type in:

`chmod -R 777 /path/to/directory`

Warning: Although this removes all restrictions to write/read access on such directory, 777 is a very open and insecure mode.